# Remove Duplicates in Dictionary while ignoring key/value order?

Tags: c#, dictionary, duplicates

Ok I'm sure my title doesn't make much sense so I'll try to explain better.  I have a Dictionary that holds two Vector2s which represent the connection between locations.  My problem is that I would like to remove duplicates ignoring the order of the key/value.  For example is the dictionary contains two key value pairs, (0, 0) (1, 1) and (1, 1) (0, 0), it will remove one of the pairs.  I hope this makes sense.  Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Given that duplicates of the same order are already taken care of by the behavior of the dictionary (you can't add 2 items of the same key) and given that Vector2 implements IEquatable and generates a meaningful hash code

```
dict.Where(v => dict.ContainsKey(v.Value) && dict[v.Value].Equals(v.Key)).Any(c => dict.Remove(c.Key));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but i just realized a major flaw for using a Dictionary in this situation which is that i need duplicate keys do you know of any other way of accomplishing what i need?  Would a hash table possibly work?

Comment: @Drok_ Hashtable doesn't allow duplicates as well. You could use a List<Tuple<Vector2, Vector2>> (i.e. list of tuples of vector2) for storing your points and then look for duplicates by creating a dictionary and mapping your list into that dictionary.

Comment: Ok thank you i may try that but for now i got it to work well enough with a class that holds two Vector2s and checking each one with a nested loop.